# Поиск всех вхождений номеров с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения, qt5

Почему не работает первая группа? Не могу понять логики. Проверял в [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/xmcAYA/1).

```
([8]{1}[0-9]{10})|([+]{1}[7]{1}[\d]{10})
```

Проверка по номерам:

```
'+79130540237' 
89261234567
```

Мне нужны все варианты совпадений.

Comment: Потому что вторая нашла совпадение. А зачем тут нужны группы? Используйте [`8[0-9]{10}|[+]7\d{10}`](https://regex101.com/r/zJV9nO/1) (или `\b(?:8[0-9]{10}|[+]7\d{10})\b`).

Comment: Удалите первые три строки списка...

Comment: Да, т.е. [`(?:\b8[0-9]{10}|[+]7\d{10})\b`](https://regex101.com/r/zJV9nO/2). Объясните, что вы делаете и зачем нужно совпадение именно первой группы.

Comment: Поменяйте выражения в скобках местами (не лучший вариант но сработает)

Comment: мне нужны все варианты совпадений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на поставленный вопрос очевиден: первая группа не нашла совпадения в `+79130540237`, поэтому её буфер пуст.

Предлагаю избавьться от *захватывающих* групп в шаблоне и оптимизировать его следующим образом:

```
(?:\b8|[+]7)[0-9]{10}\b
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/zJV9nO/3)

- `(?:\b8|[+]7)` - граница слова и `8` или `+7`
- `[0-9]{10}` - 10 цифр
- `\b`  - граница слова.

Тут `(?:...)` - это незахватывающая группа (подмаска), а `\b`  - граница слова.

Квантификатор `{1}` лишний, так как по умолчанию осуществляется поиск единичного вхождения каждой неквантифицируемой части шаблона.

Для нахождения всех совпадений в Qt5 с помощью `QRegExp`, нужно воспользоваться

```
QRegExp rx("(?:\\b8|[+]7)[0-9]{10}\\b");
QString str = "+79130540237 7-45-4 +79261234567 89261234567  792612-3 4567  89261234567";
QStringList list;
int pos = 0;

while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
    list << rx.cap(0);
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
// list: ["+79130540237", "+79261234567", "89261234567", "89261234567"]
```

Comment: меня смущает, что если использовать только первую группу, то она находит совпадение с следующим номером

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, свой комментарий. Лучше всего опубликовать код в теле вопроса и добавить тег используемого языка.

Comment: Разобрался. Нужно было в Regex flag установить флаг global

Comment: А он вам точно нужен? На каком языке пишете? Если на Python, то там нет никакого модификатора `g`.

Comment: Qt 5 использую. Флаг в https://regex101.com есть

Comment: `QRegExp` т.е., да? Там не нужен этот модификатор.